# Populate a vector of objects in a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, vector, jstl

I have a vector of objects in my servlet which I enumerate so that I can populate them in a jsp page one by one I imagine like this:

```
Enumeration<codes> ls = codes_found.elements();
            while (ls.hasMoreElements()){
                codes code=(codes)ls.nextElement();
                out.println("Code ID: "+code.getCode_id()+" Code Description: "+code.getCode_descr()+"<br/ >");
            }
```

Can someone tell me how can I populate them in jsp like this?
Thanks

Comment: Just a piece of advice, before you go coding like this read a good book or a tutorial on whatever technology you are using. It will save you a lot of trouble...

Comment: what is your problem?your code is right.Is it showing a different output??

Comment: No :). Well don't I suppose to put them in an html tag or something?

Comment: You must learn the basics. Start with [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: You really shouldn't name Java classes starting with lower case letters. `codes` should be named `Code` or something. You also might want to use a `Collection` instead of an `Enumeration`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out :). I put my `Vector<codes>` from my servlet in a session:

```
session.setAttribute("codes", codes_found);
```

Then I get the session-property with jstl:

```
<c:forEach items="${codes}" var="item">
    <input name="id" value="${item.code_id}">
    <input name="id" value="${item.code_descr}"></c:forEach>
```

I didn't know that with jstl and `${codes}` you get the actual object. Now I know :).

Comment: Indeed, you could also set it as request attribute and forward to your page. This is covered in [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) (as stated in my comment on your question).

Comment: Also, it would be good to check these two links: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197) and [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197), from both links,you will know that it's better to use `List<codes> codes = new ArrayList<codes>();`.